# Formula for the sum of words in a 3 letter algebra

Tags: combinatorics, complex-numbers, induction, combinatorics-on-words

I have two alphabets with 3 letters, $\{V,U,U^\dagger\}$ and $\{X_1,X_2,X_3\}$ where 
$$ V = X_1 + X_2 + X_3, \, U = X_1 + \omega X_2 + \omega^2 X_3, \, U^\dagger = X_1 + \omega^2 X_2 + \omega X_3 $$ 
and $\omega = e^{2\pi i /3}$.

The words I can construct in the former alphabet are restricted, such that any letter $U$ can only immediately be followed by a $V$ or a $U^\dagger$, and ultimately in the string, there must be a corresponding $U^\dagger$. Any insertion of $U^\dagger$ must be preceded by either the letter $V$ or $U^\dagger$, with an accompanying $U$ for every $U^\dagger$. Therefore $U$ and $U^\dagger$ come in a pair, and the letter $U$ will always precede the letter $U^\dagger$ in the word they are present in, and there may be multiple letters of $V$ in between them. Furthermore there can be as many pairs of $UU^\dagger$ as the length of the word permits.

Hence, the only possible 2 letter words that can be constructed are $VV$ and $UU^\dagger$.

The 3-letter words that can be constructed are $V V V, V U U^\dagger, U V U^\dagger, U U^\dagger V$.

The 4-letter words that can be constructed are $VVVV, VVUU^\dagger, VUVU^\dagger, UVVU^\dagger, VUU^\dagger V, UVU^\dagger V, UU^\dagger VV$ and $UU^\dagger UU^\dagger$.

The 5-letter words that can be constructed are $VVVVV, VVVUU^\dagger, VVUVU^\dagger, VUVVU^\dagger, UVVVU^\dagger, VVUU^\dagger V, VUVU^\dagger V, UVVU^\dagger V, VUU^\dagger VV, UVU^\dagger VV, UU^\dagger VVV, VUU^\dagger UU^\dagger, UVU^\dagger U U^\dagger, UU^\dagger V UU^\dagger, UU^\dagger UVU^\dagger$ and $UU^\dagger U U^\dagger V$.

In general there $2^{n-1}$ length $n$ words.

I would like to write down the real part of the sum of these words when mapped to the alphabet ${X_1,X_2,X_3}$.

I have explicitly shown that up to $n=6$ this gives

$$ 2^{n-1} \sum_{\sigma_1,\cdots,\sigma_n=1}^{3} \bigg(- \frac{1}{2}\bigg)^{\sum_{r=1}^n (1-\delta(\sigma_r,\sigma_{r+1}))} X_{\sigma_1}\cdots X_{\sigma_n}, \qquad \sigma_{n+1}=\sigma_1, $$

where $\delta(\sigma_r, \sigma_{r+1})$ is the Kronecker delta.

So for example, taking the sum of 2-letter words, listed above, and the expressions for $\{V,U,U^\dagger\}$ in terms of $\{X_1,X_2,X_3\}$, expanding and collecting terms. Then when we take the real part of the final result we find

$$ \text{Re}(VV + UU^\dagger) = 2\bigg(X_1 X_1 + X_2 X_2 + X_3 X_3 + \bigg(-\frac{1}{2}\bigg)^2 X_1 X_2 + \bigg(-\frac{1}{2}\bigg)^2 X_1 X_3+ \bigg(-\frac{1}{2}\bigg)^2 X_2 X_3+ \bigg(-\frac{1}{2}\bigg)^2 X_2 X_1 + \bigg(-\frac{1}{2}\bigg)^2 X_3 X_1 + \bigg(-\frac{1}{2}\bigg)^2 X_3 X_2\bigg) $$

I would like to prove (or disprove) this result for arbitrary $n$.

To do this I am basically using induction, but I have a problem in working out how to express the real part of words of the form $U^\dagger \{\text{length} \, n \, \text{words} \}$.

My question is whether there is a demonstrable way of writing down a closed sum, as above, for the words $U^\dagger \{\text{length} \, n \, \text{words} \}$. If anyone has any insight into how this might work, I would be extremely grateful.

Comment: I dont understand what you mean when talking about the restrictions on the words formed by the first alphabet.  $U$ can only be followed by $V, U^\dagger$, so then $UV$ is acceptable, right?  and Out of $9$ possible $2$-length words, only $UU$ is unacceptable, so there should be $8$ acceptable $2$-length words.  But instead you said only $2$ are acceptable.

Comment: Apologies, this was a unclear. Ultimately every U in a string must be followed by a $U^\dagger$.

Comment: I think the new description is still unclear as it does not prohibit e.g. $U^\dagger V$.  Based on your examples, maybe you mean something like the following?  $U, U^\dagger$ must come in pairs, with $U$ coming first in each pair, kinda like parentheses $($ and $)$.  And $UU$ right next to each other is not allowed.  But is $UVUU^\dagger V U^\dagger$ allowed, i.e. nested $(V()V)$?

Comment: I see the confusion, apologies. Every word can have an insertion of $U V^n U^\dagger$, in that order, where $n$ is some arbitrary integer. We prohibit $U^\dagger V$ because that ultimately every $U$ must be terminated by a $U^\dagger$, there can be no intermediary factors of $U$, only intermediary factors of $V$. Similarly a factor of $U^\dagger$ must be either followed by a string of $V$ factors or terminated with a $U$. In each word each factor of $U$ must have a corresponding factor of $U^\dagger$, conforming to the rules above.  Does this help?

Comment: @Aran 1) As of now, ${U^\dagger} V$ is still allowed by the definition given in the OP, so you need to fix this. 2) What do you mean by a "factor of $U$" ? As far as I can see, $U$ is one single variable so it has no factors except $1$ and itself.

Comment: @Aran - yeah I am still a bit confused too.  Can you do the following?  In addition to listing all allowed 2- and 3- letter words, can you pls list all possible 4-, 5-, and 6- letter words?  (According to you there are only 32 6-letter words, so it's not _too_ tedious to list them all.)  That might give us more idea what you actually mean i.e. what's allowed.  Also, maybe you can give an example of the sum as well (i.e. how you arrive at your equation that works for up to $n=6$).

Comment: I have added more detail in the OP and exampels for 4 and 5 letter words. I have included an example of the sum for $n=2$. The number of terms grows as $3^n$ in the sum. Hopefully this clarifies your concerns.

Comment: OK, i'm guessing this is the _real_ rule: an $n$-letter word can contain $k$ pairs of $U, U^\dagger$ and the rest ($n-2k$) will be $V$.  And, among the $2k$ non-$V$s, the sequence must be strictly $U, U^\dagger, U, U^\dagger...$  In particular, $UVUU^\dagger V U^\dagger$ is not allowed.  Am I correct?

Comment: @antkam Yes, this is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your formula holds true.

Speaking the "algebraic" language, we identify a set $W$ of words over an alphabet $A$ with the corresponding element $\sum_{w\in W}w$ of a free algebra on $A$ (in our case, the $\mathbb{Z}[\omega]$-algebra). If $W_n$ corresponds to the set of "allowed" words over $\{V,U,U^\dagger\}$ of length $n$ (and we consider the empty word as "allowed", so that $W_0\equiv 1$), then $$W_n=VW_{n-1}+\sum_{k=2}^{n}UV^{k-2}U^\dagger W_{n-k}\qquad(n>0)$$ since each nonempty "allowed" word begins with either $V$ or $UV^{k-2}U^\dagger$ for some $k$, with the remainder also "allowed". Now let the new variables be $X_0,X_1,X_2$ (for convenience); that is, we substitute $$V=\sum_{\sigma\in\Sigma}X_\sigma,\quad U=\sum_{\sigma\in\Sigma}\omega^\sigma X_\sigma,\quad U^\dagger=\sum_{\sigma\in\Sigma}\omega^{-\sigma} X_\sigma\qquad(\Sigma=\{0,1,2\})$$ into $W_n$. Then, if $C_n(\sigma_1,\ldots,\sigma_n)$ is the coefficient of $X_{\sigma_1}\cdots X_{\sigma_n}$ in $W_n$, we have $$C_n(\sigma_1,\ldots,\sigma_n)=C_{n-1}(\sigma_2,\ldots,\sigma_n)+\sum_{k=2}^{n}\omega^{\sigma_1-\sigma_k}C_{n-k}(\sigma_{k+1},\ldots,\sigma_n)$$ for $n>0$. But then $C_n(\sigma_1,\ldots,\sigma_n)=(1+\omega^{\sigma_1-\sigma_2})C_{n-1}(\sigma_2,\ldots,\sigma_n)$ for $n>1$, which is easily verified using induction on $n$. Thus, we arrive at the explicit formula $$\require{action}C_n(\sigma_1,\ldots,\sigma_n)=\texttip{\color{blue}{\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}(1+\omega^{\sigma_k-\sigma_{k+1}})}}{Note that we didn't use any properties of $\omega$ and $\Sigma$ until this place, inclusive}=e^{i\pi(\sigma_1-\sigma_n)/3}\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}2\cos\big(\pi(\sigma_k-\sigma_{k+1})/3\big).$$
It is easy to see that the real part of this equality is equivalent to your result.